# Add index in decreasing order

Tags: javascript, css

I have the next code in react js:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

arr.map((i, k)=> {
  <div style={{top: k+'px'}}>{i}</div>
})
```

For the `div` above i  increase the `top` with 1px. But  i want to change the logic. I want to add for `top` decreasing order of `k`. I want to get next:

```html
first `k` will be 6,
second `k` will be 5,
third `k` will be 4,
forth `k` will be 3,
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this-

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

arr.map((i, k)=> {
  return <div style={{top: (arr.length - k) + 'px'}}>{i}</div>
})
```